# How to generate numbered list with line break using R whisker templating engine

Tags: r, mustache, template-engine, r-whisker

I have the following data:

```
data <- list( name = "Chris",
             children_names = c("Alex", "John")
            )
```

Using R's templating engine [*whisker*](https://github.com/edwindj/whisker), I want to get this output,
when rendered:

```
I am Chris
My children are:
    Child No 1 is Alex
    Child No 2 is John
```

This is my current code:

```
library(whisker)
template <- 
'I am {{name}}
My children are:
{{children_names}}
'

data <- list( name = "Chris",
             children_names = c("Alex", "John")
            
            )

text <- whisker.render(template, data)
cat(text)

# which produces:

# I am Chris
# My children are:
# Alex,John
```

Which is not what I want.
What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably already figured this out, but in case you haven't:

```
library(whisker)

template <- 
  'I am {{name}} \n
  My children are: \n
  {{#children_names}}
  Child No {{number}} is {{cname}}
  {{/children_names}}'

data <- list( 
  name = "Chris",
  children_names = list(
    list(cname = "Alex", number = 1), list(cname = "John", number = 2)
  )
)

text <- whisker.render(template, data)
cat(text)

# I am Chris 
# 
# My children are: 
#   
# Child No 1 is Alex
# Child No 2 is John
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [jinjar](https://davidchall.github.io/jinjar/) package:

```r
library(jinjar)

template <- 'I am {{ name }}
My children are:
    {% for child in children %}Child No {{ loop.index1 }} is {{ child }}
    {% endfor -%}
'

text <- render(template, name = "Chris", children = c("Alex", "John"))
cat(text)
#> I am Chris
#> My children are:
#>     Child No 1 is Alex
#>     Child No 2 is John
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>